# How to download iframe video with C#

Tags: c#, iframe, c#-4.0, download

for example how can i download this kind of url video

```
<iframe src="/neo/stats/dlcount_iframe.php?movie_id=708969&game_id=12830&type=flv&page=player&vidtype=flv&vidhd=1" width="1" height="1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

using microsoft visual studio 2010 C# netframework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  They use streaming to ***prevent*** downloading of material.  if they wanted you do download your own copy, they'd provide it as an MPEG. .mov, .wmv, or some other type of file.

Even if you can, you'd be violating copyright laws. Like I said, if they WANTED you do do it, they'd provide a method.  Any use of the video other than what the owner intends for it is a violation of copyright, even if the Internet makes copyright infringement easy in most cases.

**Edit**

Downloading a file is very straightforward.  There's an article here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/

and an example with specifyng the name on your PC here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx

Comment: i will download flv game trailer videos. so they are not copyrighted. and they are not streaming since IDM can extract the direct download link from this iframe url.

Comment: I can't go to that sort of site from work, but I'd double-check to ensure you're not mistaken before attempting it.  I could be wrong, but they would have to explicitly grant permission to use, download, or reporst their videos for you to be right on that.  http://www.templetons.com/brad/copymyths.html

Comment: ok the website i will use also gives direct vmw download links :) just tell me how to download vmw link with C# and rename the downloaded file :)

Comment: Glad to.. Edit coming.  
Sorry to hassle you so much about the copyright laws.

Comment: yes thanks for link. i am glad that they provide even mp4 file :D